Installed 20.04 after installing ROS & Nvidia driver packages there was a pop-up insisting restart Ubuntu didn't boot again only a blinking underscore
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/HP/DI.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt.efi 
                       /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA.efi 
                       /efi/HP/SystemDiags/CryptRSA.efi 
                       /efi/HP/SystemDiags/DI.efi 
                       /efi/HP/SystemDiags/SysDiags.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on nvme0n1p4
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 8 or 10 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: NVIDIA Corporation Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] from NVIDIA Corporation Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, focal, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: F.21(15.21) from Insyde
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0002,2001,3003,2002,2004
Boot0000* USB CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI) (SanDisk) UsbWwid(781,5590,0,4C53000122121310554)/CDROM(1,0x573ca4,0x7f00)RC
Boot0001* Network Adapter (IPv6 UEFI)   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(28c5c8d57401,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,e7fc62c2-444a-4c66-9398-d6494479efac,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,e7fc62c2-444a-4c66-9398-d6494479efac,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot3002* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
Boot3003* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC

07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
64e4182ead3316166f817dcc6131cd7a   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
522f1fff3eaefbaeb449d98436d24041   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
b75497a043790d1f9c70c2c64b52386c   nvme0n1p1/HP/DI.efi
d4646b0af24b169d62bc44cff8967793   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
522f1fff3eaefbaeb449d98436d24041   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
07e25dcaf57c776875f78fa36827c58e   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
6ca548265bd5d9e650044f4a1e594ef7   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt.efi
a96537c7fa189564b38473456b33f7e5   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA.efi
a96537c7fa189564b38473456b33f7e5   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/CryptRSA.efi
b75497a043790d1f9c70c2c64b52386c   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/DI.efi
54908a8ff3b6168a4fc200d0ceccc68e   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/SysDiags.efi
2fc8a50a26d396e4b817f658cc9b1f26   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
5e943a16a4105e7c2b22f3113d329ef9   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
0dddc55d593fc13c3ab3cb750e1a188a   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p4   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.89 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: F7293756-B0A5-4B08-80ED-9A0147F6B969
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
nvme0n1p2     534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3     567296  411762687  411195392 196.1G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4  411762688 1989887999 1578125312 752.5G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p5 1998962688 2000396287    1433600   700M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p6 1989888000 1998872575    8984576   4.3G Linux swap
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sda: 14.33 GiB, 15376000000 bytes, 30031250 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x405a23c7
     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *          0  8498951  8498952  4.1G  0 Empty
sda2       5717156  5725283     8128    4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sda3       8499200 30031249 21532050 10.3G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:15.4GB:scsi:512:512:unknown:SanDisk Ultra:;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:KBG50ZNV1T02 KIOXIA:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:211GB:211GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:211GB:1019GB:808GB:ext4::;
6:1019GB:1023GB:4600MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
5:1023GB:1024GB:734MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

nvme0n1: 976012MiB:976056MiB:44.0MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda         iso9660  2023-03-16-15-57-27-00                                                    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS amd64 
├─sda1      iso9660  2023-03-16-15-57-27-00               405a23c7-01                          Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS amd64 
├─sda2      vfat     1544-BBA2                            405a23c7-02                                                   
└─sda3      ext4     de2d694a-f890-46ba-a27a-349fe2b9eec1 405a23c7-03                          writable                 
nvme0n1                                                                                                                 
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     BEBB-7B1D                            e7fc62c2-444a-4c66-9398-d6494479efac SYSTEM                   EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               133f72f6-098a-4fdd-9f1e-f2f8267bdf3f                          Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     18E6E384E6E3610C                     ae71241e-a3f4-4e4c-8a84-0f533d4b45b0 Windows                  Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ext4     084a4c52-2870-4bf5-96b7-720fe03a8958 7d4d48d2-65b9-40cd-adde-fde1b6bcb1fa                          
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs     B0D2E387D2E34FE0                     fe0efd42-f123-4e6a-b055-9f604116c25f Windows RE tools         Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p6 swap     be0ddab4-ead0-47a8-9c81-05a240943943 fbec358e-c8e2-4b90-86be-0b75fb32dbc9                          

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                                191.2M  25% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                                  129G  34% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4                                                684.2G   2% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5                                                 67.2M  90% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/sda1                                                          0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1                                                vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                                fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4                                                ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/nvme0n1p5                                                fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 084a4c52-2870-4bf5-96b7-720fe03a8958 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p4/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   084a4c52-2870-4bf5-96b7-720fe03a8958
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-BEBB-7B1D
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p4/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
UUID=084a4c52-2870-4bf5-96b7-720fe03a8958 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=BEBB-7B1D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=be0ddab4-ead0-47a8-9c81-05a240943943 none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p4/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme0n1p4: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 818.474731445 = 878.830551040  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             2
 660.234371185 = 708.921257984  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 660.234371185 = 708.921257984  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-122-generic                2
 836.312496185 = 897.983705088  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-67-generic                 2
 836.312496185 = 897.983705088  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 419.878318787 = 450.840911872  boot/initrd.img                                1
 419.878318787 = 450.840911872  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-122-generic             1
 797.065933228 = 855.843028992  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-67-generic              1
 797.065933228 = 855.843028992  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

=================== nvme0n1p4: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18224 Dec  2  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 Dec  2  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13101 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Dec  2  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Dec  2  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Jul  3  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec  2  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Dec  2  2022 41_custom



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p4,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)

